# UWP: Raise Key Down programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I want to manage the listview while the text field is in focus. I mean the following case: I'm writing some text into the text box, but I am able to manage the list view selection in the same time by some keys(Up, Down).

I tried to change the SelectedIndex property, but I lose the automatic scrolling of the list view in this case.

I think it could be solved by raising key down event with a special key (Up, Down) for the listview - is there any way to do it?

Comment: Is the `TextBox` inside the `ListView` or outside ?

Comment: The textbox is outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to use [ScrollIntoView()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.scrollintoview) method of **ListView** whenever you set the **SelectedIndex** of your ListView just follow it up with ScrollIntoView. you do it in 2 ways.

1. subscribe to **SelectionChanged** event and scroll the new selected item into view.
2. instead of setting SelectedIndex you can set **SelectedItem** and then scroll that item into view.
3. After setting the SelectedIndex, just get the item of that index and then scroll that item into view.